# How can I extract an element from a returned json "record" in Javascript/jQuery (Meteor)?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, meteor, http-get

If a REST call returns this json:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"number":"0871632810","status":"YES","carrier_name":"ATT Mobility","carrier_id":"","sms_address":"0871632810@txt.att.net","mms_address":"0871632810@mms.att.net"}}
```

...how can I access one element from it - e.g., if I want the "sms_address" portion?

This:

```
'getTextAddrAsEmailAddr': function(phone) {
    this.unblock();
    var restcall = 'http://www.reminder.com/phone.check.php?number=' + phone;
    console.log('restcall is '+ restcall);
    return Meteor.call("GET", restcall);
}
```

...returns "undefined"

When I took a flyer on this:

```
return Meteor.call("GET", restcall).sms_address;
```

...I got: "*Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'insertPerson' TypeError: Cannot read property 'sms_address' of undefined
    at Meteor.methods.getTextAddrAsEmailAddr*"

So what do I need to do get at that value?

### UPDATE

I am now trying this:

```
function getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(scope, phone) {
    scope.unblock();
    var restcall = 'http://www.reminder.com/phone.check.php?number=' + phone;
    return HTTP.get(restcall);
}

Meteor.methods({
    'insertPerson': function(firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes) {
        console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
        check(firstname, String);
        . . .
        console.log('phone is ' + phone);
        var textAddrAsEmailAddr = getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(this, phone);
        console.log('textAddrAsEmailAddr is ' + textAddrAsEmailAddr);

        People.insert({
            per_firstname: firstname,
            per_lastname: lastname,
            per_streetaddr1: streetaddr1,
            per_streetaddr2: streetaddr2,
            per_placename: placename,
            per_stateorprov: stateorprov,
            per_zipcode: zipcode,
            per_emailaddr: emailaddr,
            per_phone: phone,
            per_textaddrasemailaddr: phone,
            per_notes: notes,
            per_createdBy: this.userId
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

...but still get, "*Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'insertPerson' Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.(…) Error: Can't make a blocking HTTP call from the client; callback required.*"

I don't know where this missing callback is supposed to go. insertPersion() is called like this:

```
Meteor.call('insertPerson', firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    Session.set("lastErrMsg", err.message);
  } else {
    alert(firstname + ' ' + lastname + ' inserted');
    $('#firstName').val("");
    $('#lastName').val("");
    $('#streetAddress1').val("");
    $('#streetAddress2').val("");
    $('#placename').val("");
    $('#stateorprovince').val("");
    $('#postalcode').val("");
    $('#emailAddr').val("");
    $('#inputPhone').val("");
    $('#notes').val("");

    $('#firstName').focus();
  } // else
}); // Meteor call
```

...from the template's events method:

### UPDATE 2

So with this modified code (based on the suggestion to "change it to: if (Meteor.isServer)) {return HTTP.get(restcall); } else {return 'will_be_filled_in_on_server';}"):

```
function getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(scope, phone) {
    scope.unblock();
    var restcall = 'http://www.reminder.com/number.phone.php?number=' + phone;
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      return HTTP.get(restcall);
    }
    else {
      return 'will_be_filled_in_on_server';
    }
}

Meteor.methods({
    'insertPerson': function(firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes) {
        console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
        check(firstname, String);
        . . .
        console.log('phone is ' + phone);
        var textAddrAsEmailAddr = getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(this, phone);
        console.log('textAddrAsEmailAddr is ' + textAddrAsEmailAddr);
```

...I don't get err msgs, but for the last console.log, I get "*textAddrAsEmailAddr is will_be_filled_in_on_server*"

I was hoping that would be the value from the REST call, but it simply falls through to the else clause.

### UPDATE 3

I also tried this:

```
// function getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(scope, phone) {
//   scope.unblock();
//   var restcall = 'http://www.xminder.com/number.check.php?number=' + phone;
//   if (Meteor.isServer) {
//     return HTTP.get(restcall);
//   } else {
//     return 'will_be_filled_in_on_server';
//   }
// }

Meteor.methods({
  'insertPerson': function(firstname, lastname, streetaddr1, streetaddr2, placename, stateorprov, zipcode, emailaddr, phone, notes) {
      console.log('insertPerson reached'); // TODO: Remove before deploying
      check(firstname, String);
      check(lastname, String);
      check(streetaddr1, String);
      check(streetaddr2, String);
      check(placename, String);
      check(stateorprov, String);
      check(zipcode, String);
      check(emailaddr, String);
      check(phone, String);
      check(notes, String);

      console.log('phone is ' + phone);
      var textAddrAsEmailAddr = getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(this, phone);
      Meteor.call("getTextAddrAsEmailAddr", phone, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error.reason);
          return;
        }
      })
      console.log('textAddrAsEmailAddr is ' + textAddrAsEmailAddr);

      People.insert({
        per_firstname: firstname,
        per_lastname: lastname,
        per_streetaddr1: streetaddr1,
        per_streetaddr2: streetaddr2,
        per_placename: placename,
        per_stateorprov: stateorprov,
        per_zipcode: zipcode,
        per_emailaddr: emailaddr,
        per_phone: phone,
        per_textaddrasemailaddr: phone,
        per_notes: notes,
        per_createdBy: this.userId
      });
      return true;
    },
    'getTextAddrAsEmailAddr': function(phone) {
      return getTextAddrAsEmailAddr(this, phone);
         this.unblock();
        var restcall = 'http://www.reminder.com/phone.check.php?number=' + phone;
        console.log('restcall is '+ restcall);
        return Meteor.call("GET", restcall);
        //return Meteor.call("GET", restcall).sms_address;
    }
});
```

...but both the browser console and the command prompt console complain, "*Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'insertPerson' ReferenceError: getTextAddrAsEmailAddr is not defined(…) ReferenceError: getTextAddrAsEmailAddr is not defined
    at Meteor.methods.insertPerson*"

But it's right there - as you can see above, the "getTextAddrAsEmailAddr" method *is* defined.

Okay, I think "Meteor In Action" has a section on how to do this; I will try their methodology tonight or sometime this weekend.

Comment: your call doesn't have a callback

Comment: oh wait a second, you are trying to `call` a URL. That's wrong. You need to use `HTTP.get`, but also there you need a callback.

Comment: what does scope.unblock() do?

Comment: The missing callback goes here:  `HTTP.get(restcall, CALLBACK);`
The return value is always undefined when you call this, the callback will contain the result.

Comment: change it to:  if (Meteor.isServer)) {return HTTP.get(restcall); } else {return '_will_be_filled_in_on_server_';}

Comment: You can use HTTP.get without callback on the server, this will allow the simulated method on the client to proceed

Comment: And read the link in the first comment

Comment: @JeremyK: I see no link in the first comment ("your call doesn't have a callback") -- or any of them, for that matter.